# Java Graphics repaint() on ButtonClick

Tags: java, swing

I have this code and want to repaint my graphic when the Button gets pressed:

```
public class JDraw extends JFrame {

/**
 * Draws a figur in a JFrame.
 * The color of it is random and can get changed by a button.
 */

public static JButton okButton = new JButton("change color");

public JDraw(String newTitel) {
    super.setTitle(newTitel);
}

//Main method
public static void main(String str[]) {
    JDraw window = new JDraw("Graphic");
    window.setSize(300, 450);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //JDraw.repaint(); <-- problem
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void paint(final Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int r1 = rand.nextInt(255);
    int b1 = rand.nextInt(255);
    int g1 = rand.nextInt(255);
    g.setColor(new Color(r1, g1, b1));

    //head
    g.drawOval(100, 50, 100, 100);
    g.fillOval(100, 50, 100, 100); // filled
    //more drawing stuff.....

}
}
```

However I have no idea how to do it, because I cant do the repaint in my ActionPerfomed.
Error: non-static method repaint() cannot be referenced from a static context

I hope somebody can help. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the following call in your `actionPerformed`:

```
window.repaint();
```

To be able to reference `window` from within you `actionPerformed`, you need to make your window variable `final`:

```
final JDraw window = ...;
```

However, if I can suggest a few improvements:

1. Don't extend `JFrame`
2. Don't override `paint(Graphics)` of `JFrame`
3. Instead create a class that extends `JComponent` or `JPanel` and set it as the content pane of the `JFrame`
4. Instead of overrding `paint(Graphics)`, rather override `paintComponent(Graphics)`
5. Your `okButton` should not be `static`. Instead move all your code in a non-static method like `initUI()` and have a code like `new JDraw().initUI();`
6. Wrap the code starting your UI in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` so that your UI is properly initiated from the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: +1: However, I do not agree with improvement number 1. And don't extend JPanel, but JComponent instead.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Agreed that extending `JComponent` may be a better choice although extending `JPanel` automatically bring opacity (by default at least). For commment #1, unless you are adding behaviour to a class, there is no need to extend it and composition is always a better choice. That is a philosophical choice, but IMO "dont extend" if you can "compose", this will provide better code and mainly more maintainable code. In this case, there is absolutely no need to extend.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Note that if the code draws in a `BufferedImage` that is displayed in a label, there is no need to extend either `JComponent` or `JPanel`, and no need to repaint anything (until new drawings are made on the image).

Answer (score 5):

You can't refer to the class JDraw. You should use an object instead. The object in your case is `window`. So, use:

```
window.repaint();
```

It is like saying: *Human, walk to the door.* Human is the class. You can't tell Human to do something, you need an instance of Human, like Obama or Santa Claus. In your case: you can't tell JDraw to repaint, but the object of type JDraw, i.e.: `window`.