# Cannot delay the rendering rectangle on after the other

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, rendering, delay

i'm currently looking for a way to delay the rendering of some rectangles within this block code that i'm writing.

```
 g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100); 

 // some code to delay the rendering

 g.fillRect(350, 300, 100, 100);
```

i've been trying different ways to accomplish this but nothing has worked. My most recent effort was:

```
g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);  

ActionListener a = new ActionListener() { 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
   g.fillRect(350, 300, 100, 100);  
   repaint();
       } }; 
Timer timer = new Timer(3000,a); 

timer.start();
```

BUT THIS DOES NOT GENERATE THE RECTANGLE AFTER THE THREE SECONDS have passed.

If anyone has the time to answer this question, please do so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need the first rectangle to be displayed then a wait of three seconds after which the second rectangle will be displayed

Comment: I would guess the issue is related to the call to paint(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007338/java-graphics-repaint-on-buttonclick

Comment: Frustration is stepping in. I can't seem to figure out why it's not being displayed after the three seconds

Comment: I am quite certain the timer is firing. You need to ensure that the repainting life cycle is properly followed.

Comment: The timer is working well. I tested with println statements and it's firing away. however the rectangle isn't displaying

Comment: I having off graphics2d for a while. I just tried to point in the direction you should look into. I think the link I provided should help.

Comment: I'm relatively new to graphics2D so i'm still uncertain about some concepts